# minimal value of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos(x)-ax\right)^2\,dx$$

and I need to know for which a the function is minimal.

so I can take the derivative of the integral, but what should I do with the boundries of the integral?

so I think this should work, but I'm not sure, and thats why asking:

(cos(pi/2) - a(pi/2))² - (cos(0)-a(0))²

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you take the derivative of the integral, then you need to use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: That integral is a function of $a$, the limits do not depend on $a$, you can just take the derivative inside the integral.

Comment: but the function is a function of $x$, not of $a$

Comment: @user2239704 The term can also be seen as a function of $a$, assumed $x$ to be constant in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could evaluate the integral directly and take a derivative, or vice-versa:

Regard this as a function of $a$; that is,

$$f(a) = \int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos x - ax)^2 dx$$

This can be differentiated with respect to $a$, giving

$$f'(a) = \int_0^{\pi/2} 2 (\cos x - ax) (-x) dx = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} (ax^2 - x \cos x )dx$$

Now evaluate the integral by parts, to find

$$f'(a) = 2\left(a \frac{(\pi/2)^3}{3} - \frac 1 2 (\pi - 2)\right)$$

Likewise, the second derivative is given by

$$f''(a) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 dx > 0$$

Hence the only critical point is also a minimum.

Comment: So I can find the $a$ if I calculate $f'(a) = 0$?

Comment: @user2239704 Yes. It's a standard minimization problem now.

Comment: I have a little different solution for $f'(a) = 2a(pi/2)³/3 - (pi - 2)$ without the $(1/2)$ because you have the multiplier $2$ at the beginning, and with your solution it only multiplies the first part of the minus

Answer (score 3):

One way to see the problem is to find the minimal distance between the vector $x\mapsto\cos x$ and the subspace $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{id})$ in the vector space of continuous functions over $[0,\frac \pi 2]$ endowed with the inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)g(x)dx$$
so we have to find $a$ such that
$$\langle \cos-a\operatorname{id},\operatorname{id}\rangle=\int_0^{\pi/2}x(\cos x-ax)dx=0$$
we find 
$$a=\frac{12}{\pi^3}(\pi-2)$$

Comment: No my answer is correct check yours.

Comment: yeah I checked it, and with the second time writing it down I saw it..

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Asalomo alaykom Sami.

Answer (score 2):

I think firstly you solve the definite integral to find this function:

$$f(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos(x)-ax)^2dx=(2-\pi)a+\frac{1}{4}\pi+\frac{1}{24}a^2\pi^3$$ then solve $f'(a)=0$ and also use [the Second derivation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) to find the proper possible $a$.

Comment: I believe this is the simplest answer to go for.  I thought of doing this too.

Comment: yeah, but how can I now find the $f'(a)$ without the function..